# Rust lifetime error: lifetime may not live long enough

Tags: rust

I have an error that i do not understand when i compile my rust code.

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\tls_rustls.rs:88:9
   |
51 | impl<'a> Tls<Certificate> for EstClientRustls<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
52 |     fn open(&mut self, host: &str, port: i32, chain: &Vec<Certificate>) {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
88 |         self.tls = Some(tls);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

The code that generates the error is:

```
pub trait Tls<T> {
    fn open(&mut self, host: &str, port: i32, chain: &Vec<T>);
    fn close(&self);
}

pub struct EstClientRustls<'a> {
    client: Option<ClientConnection>,
    sock: Option<TcpStream>,
    tls: Option<Stream<'a, ClientConnection, TcpStream>>
}

impl<'a> Tls<Certificate> for EstClientRustls<'a> {

    fn open(&mut self, host: &str, port: i32, chain: &Vec<Certificate>) {
      let client = ClientConnection::new(rc_config, tls_server_name).unwrap();
      let sock = TcpStream::connect(host_port).unwrap();

      self.client = Some(client);
      self.sock = Some(sock);

      let tls = Stream::new(
        self.client.as_mut().unwrap(),
        self.sock.as_mut().unwrap());

      self.tls = Some(tls);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me?
Technical notes:
rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)
libraries:

- rustls -> "0.20.7"
- rustls-pemfile -> "1.0.1"
- x509-parser -> "0.14.0"

Comment: your error say you create an variable name `tls` it's type of `Stream`

now stream has lifetime `'a` so compiler can't guarantee that `tls` variable live enough, you must add `'a` lifetime to `self ` too

Comment: Just a tip - Avoid amending your question with the solution; post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solution thanks to Ali Mirghasemi

Change the trait definition to

```
pub trait Tls<'a, T> {
    fn open(&'a mut self, host: &str, port: i32, chain: &Vec<T>);
    fn close(&self);
}
```

and the implementation itself to

```
fn open(&'a mut self, host: &str, port: i32, chain: &Vec<Certificate>) {
```

solve the problem